# Find out what sectors are a file on a hard drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, sectors, assembly

How would I go about finding what sectors a file's data is on so i would be able to delete the file via bootable assembly code.

Eg:

File: C:\system.sys
Location: sector 1837,1739,2736 etc

Or some thing like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WinHex](http://www.x-ways.net/winhex/) to find the location of the file in the HDD.